# Shaded area made with `annotate()` doesn't cover the full height of the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with a shaded area like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

xmin <- 6
xmax <- 7
ymin <- min(iris$Sepal.Width)
ymax <- max(iris$Sepal.Width)

p <- iris |> 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  annotate(
    "rect",
    xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, 
    fill='pink', alpha=0.5
  ) +
  geom_point()

p
```

[image]

As you can see, even if I take the max and min of the y-axis, the shaded area doesn’t go from the very bottom to the very top. However, `geom_vline()` for example can do that:

```r
p + geom_vline(xintercept = 5)
```

[image]

Is there an easy way to extend the shaded area so that it covers the whole height of the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just noticed I could use `-Inf` and `Inf` for the y-axis limits...

```r
library(ggplot2)

xmin <- 6
xmax <- 7
ymin <- min(iris$Sepal.Width) - 5
ymax <- max(iris$Sepal.Width) + 5

iris |> 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  annotate(
    "rect",
    xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, 
    fill='pink', alpha=0.5
  ) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]